Does Facebook allow collecting comments from public posts or pages?
I need to collect comments from public facebook posts which i'm unable to do.
**Is it permissible to collect comments from public Facebook posts or pages? **
I’m encountering issues with the Facebook Graph API and can’t tell if it’s due to a policy change or a coding error. Can anyone recommend an easier method to achieve this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
